# Can ping federate support an SP with more than one IssuerID

Tags: saml-2.0, pingfederate

My application serves as an SP and interacts with a bunch of IDPs. One of them is a client's instance of Ping Federate. We have to change our IssuerID and I would like to know if Ping Federate can support multiple IssuerIDs. I know in AzureAD I can set up an application so that it is prepared to handle multiple IssuerIDs, with one set as "Default". Is there something similar in Ping Federate? I want to ask my client to make this change but I want to make sure its possible before asking them to change any settings.

Comment: Is this relevant?  https://support.pingidentity.com/s/article/Creating-multiple-connections-with-a-single-partner

> "In PingFederate, you can only have a single connection (and thus one protocol) with a partner that presents themselves as a given Entity ID (e.g. a SAML AuthnRequest Issuer), however, a partner might request that PF present its messages as if it were two different entities (e.g., such that SAML assertions have different issuers)."

Answer (score 0):

PingFederate can absolutely support multiple Issuer IDs from the same Service Provider (e.g., you are changing entity ID from `sp.issuer.com` to `identity.issuer.com`) on the same "connection".

What PingFederate cannot do is have two different connections that have the same entity ID, (e.g., two connections that both want to use `sp.issuer.com`).